# Path.GetExtension(file.FileName) gives possible Nullreference warning

Tags: c#, .net, resharper, nullreferenceexception

When I add  `".ToLowerInvariant()"`
 to  `Path.GetExtension(file.FileName)`, ReSharper gives a warning for a possible Nullreference exception.

I have tried to following, but warning is nog going away. What am i missing?

```
if (file != null && Path.GetExtension(file.FileName) != null)
            {
                switch (Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLowerInvariant())
                {
                    case ".jpg":
                    case ".png":
                    case ".gif":
                    case ".jpeg":
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;

                }
}
```

Comment: Try giving full path of file Path.GetExtension(fullpath). Also sheck the path is null or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `ToLowerInvariant()` is being called on the outcome of Path.GetExtension(). There is no guarantee that Path.GetExtension() will return anything meaningful (if file.Filename is null for example).

Best to check that the outcome of Path.GetExtension isnt null, before you call anything else on it. (or call ToLower() on file.FileName before you put it into GetExtension, either way make sure you know exactly what you're putting into GetExtension() or you cant make any guarantees that what you get out will be what you were after).

Answer (score 1):

So [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx) GetExtension will only return null if you pass in a FileName that's null.

> The extension of the specified path (including the period "."), or
>   Nothing[Null], or String.Empty. If path is Nothing[Null], GetExtension returns
>   Nothing[Null]. If path does not have extension information, GetExtension
>   returns String.Empty.

If you check `if (file != null && file.FileName != null)` first you're safe.

You can also make the resharper warning go away with

```
if (file != null) 
{
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
    if (extension != null) //will be null if file.FileName is null
    {
        switch(extension.ToLowerInvariant())
        { 
          //..snip
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding a condition that is never fulfilled sounds like a dubious design choice to me. You also added a bug by using `ToLower` instead of `ToLowerInvariant`

Comment: @CodeInChaos agreed. Modified to remove redundant check.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a false warning.

So it sounds like ReSharper doesn't understand that `Path.GetExtension(file.FileName)` does not change between your test and the time it's used in `ToLowerInvariant`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a resharper warning, you simply need to check for nulls.

**Here is an example:**

```
var extension = Path.GetExtension(myFile.FileName);

if (extension == null || extension.ToLower() != ".jpg")
{
    lblOutput.Text = @"The file must have an extension of JPG";
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well, I had the same problem and the simple fix is

make sure in your .cshtml file the form post method has

> enctype="multipart/form-data"

```
<form method="post" asp-for="Upsert" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```